# Instantiating Django's User Model

Tags: python, django

I have seen the different ways of creating an instance of Django's User Model. Which follows best practices in Django development

**1.**

```
from django.config import settings

class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**2.**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly.

If you later change the user model, by setting another value for the [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-user-model), then the `ForeignKey`s to that model will thus refer to the *new* user model.

The Django documentation also has a section on [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model):

> If you reference **`User` directly** (for example, by referring to it in a foreign key), your code will not work in projects where the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting has been changed to a different user model.

If you need a reference to the user *class*, for example in a view, you can make use of the [**`get_user_model()`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model).